# wpf find inner grid inside style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a button style defined in xaml, inside i have an storyboard and among other things a grid. The storyboard set the opacity of the grid to 0.1. The question is how to restore it via code. I think i can access the grid and set the opacity to 1 but i can not find a way to get the grid via c#.

Here is the code:

xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="BevelWLButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Name="bbtemplate">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="FadeOut" >
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.05"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>

                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Grid x:Name="grid">
                        -------------- up is the grid i find
    </Style>
```

the buttons are created by code and the style is setted properly

here i begin the storyboard:

```
var story = btn.Template.Resources["FadeOut"] as Storyboard;
                if (story != null)
                {
                    story = story.Clone();
                    story.Begin(btn,btn.Template);
                }
```

but when i try to

```
currentButton.Resources["grid"]; or currentButton.Template.Resources["grid"];
```

the result is null. So, i can not restablish opacity

Any Idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
Grid gridInTemplate = (Grid)currentButton.Template.FindName("grid", currentButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `currentButton.Template.FindName("grid", currentButton) as Grid`